# Kali new install and doing an update and it says i am missing firmware and its frozen on 4 different processing triggers

Tags: updates, kali-linux, firmware, processing

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_asd.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_me.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_pfp.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_ce.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_smc.in for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_smc.bin fr module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_dmcu.bin for module amdgpu
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-12) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-2) ...
Processing triggers for postgresql-common (225) ...
supported-versions: WARNING! Unknown distribution: kali
debian found in ID_LIKE, treating as Debian
supported-versions: WARNING: Unknown Debian release: 2021.2
Building PostgreSQL dictionaries from installed myspell/hunspell pacages...
  en_us
Removing obsolete dictionary files:
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.69) ...
```

Comment: Compulsory link - [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: Run sudo apt autoremove, restart and update again.

Answer (score 0):

The reason can be failed **grub installation** for Kali linux, after major updates.
You should fix entry of Kali from NVRAM, to do that, you could update the **grub**.

Once you boot into Kali, open terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo update-initramfs -u

sudo update-grub
```

**Remember to reboot your system after this.**